# Modify result of first observable in second observable and return updated result

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable, subscribe

I have a method `exampleMethod()` that returns the result of 2 consecutive service calls (`getData1()` and `getData2()`), whereas `getData2()` must modify the data returned by `getData1()` before `exampleMethod()` returns. Currently, the nested service call executes after we've already returned from `exampleMethod()` and that is too late. I know calling a subscription inside another observable is a bad practice and might be causing the issue, so I'm asking what's the right approach to do it. Example code below. Thanks!

```
exampleMethod() {
    return this.myService.getData1()
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          res.orders = someValue;
          return res;
        }),
        map(res => {
          res.orders.forEach((order: any) => {
            this.myService.getData2()
              .pipe(
                tap((orders: any[]) =>
                  order.status = orders.find(o=> o.number === order.number).status // <<====== this resolves after we've already returned from exampleMethod()
                )
              ).subscribe();
          });
          return res; // <<====== status value of res.orders not set
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: I believe you want switchmap

Comment: yeah ,have a look at `concatMap` or `mergeMap` or maybe `forkJoin` as well

Comment: If I replace the second `map()` call with `switchMap()` and get rid of `subscribe()` I'm getting: "ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable"

Comment: Rule of thumb: any time you are facing embedded subscription you can replace it with return correspondent Observable and have 1 subscribe() at the very end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in saying inner subscription isn't elegant. You'd need here RxJS `switchMap` operator with `forkJoin` function for multiple simultaneous requests.

Try the following

```js
exampleMethod(): Observable<any> {   // <-- define return type here
  return this.myService.getData1().pipe(
    map(res => ({...res, res.orders: someValue})),
    switchMap(res =>
      forkJoin(
        res.orders.map(order =>
          this.myService.getData2().pipe(map((orders: any[]) =>       // <-- pip the `map` operator here
            ({...res, res.status: orders.find(o => o.number === order.number).status})
          ))
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Edit: Include `pipe` for RxJS `map`

Comment: Struggling with "TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable." on the `res.orders.map()` call.

Comment: I overlooked the `pipe` function for `map` operator in line 7. I've updated the answer. Please try the solution again.

Comment: Using your and the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590846/nested-observable-promise-trying-to-block-wait-flow-in-mapper-function as a guidance I was able to construct a working solution. Only thing that differs from your implementation is that I'm pushing the inner observables to an array and then call `forkJoin()` on it, then do some modifications and use `mapTo()` to map the result to the higher level observable before returning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with higher-order Observables. I suspect `switchMap` might not be what you're looking for, but rather [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) or [concatAll](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concatall).

```js
return this.myService.getData1().pipe(
    map((res) => {
      res.orders = ["someValue"];
      return res;
    }),
    map((res) => 
      // <-- use switch map to internally subscribe to inner observable
      res.orders.forEach((order: any) => 
        this.myService.getData2().pipe(
          first(),
          tap(/* do something */)
        );
      )
    ),
    concatAll(), // <-- concat all inner-observables values in order
    last() // ensure that only the last value is emitted to outer observable
  );
```

One thing to keep in mind though, an observable will not emit values synchronously. therefor the `exampleMethod()` will always return before the observable has processed any values. One way, although I wouldn't recommend it, is to await the completion of the observable in an async method:

```js
async function exampleMethod(){
    return await this.dataService.getData()
       .pipe(/* whatever*/ )
       .toPromise(); // this will resolve when the observable is complete
}
```